# Why is my dataframe not recognised as one when using R's ROSE package?

Tags: r, error-handling, prediction

While building a predictive model for binary classification, I stratified my data into training, validation and test sets. They're put into a list of data frames and called when needed. As one outcome is a minority class, I want to balance my training set using various functions under R's ROSE package.

However, I want to toggle between different balancing methods offered by ROSE for experimentation without having chunks of the same code repeated throughout my R scripts, thus I've made a function, Balance, to do so. Balance takes in a data frame and a key, which toggles between the package's functions.

Problem is: When I call Balance with a data frame from my list as input, I get an error stating that as.data.frame.default can't coerce class '"function"' to a data.frame. I've provided a simplified version of my code below.

If anyone could take a look, I'd appreciate it. I'm quite new to R and modelling as well, and would appreciate any suggestions.

```
# make dataframe with variable and predictor columns; minority class: Predictor == 1
dataset <- as.data.frame(runif(100, min = 0, max = 100))
colnames(dataset) <- c("Var")
dataset$Predictor <- ifelse(dataset$Var < 20, 1, 0)

# stratify into train and test sets
prop <- c(train = .8, test = .2)
g <- sample(cut(
  seq(nrow(dataset)),
  nrow(dataset) * cumsum(c(0, prop)),
  labels = names(prop)))
ls <- split(dataset, g)

# balance using different functions in ROSE package
library(ROSE)
Balance <- function(df, key) {
  if (key == "under") {
    return(ovun.sample(
      Predictor ~.,
      data = df, 
      method = "under", 
      N = nrow(subset(df, Predictor == 1)) * 2)$data)
  } else if (key == "over") {
      return(ovun.sample(
        Predictor ~., 
        data = df, 
        method = "over", 
        N = nrow(subset(df, Predictor == 0)) * 2)$data)
  }
}
```

I'm certain Balance returns a data frame based on the input key, and calling class(ls$train) also gives data.frame. But:

```
# this gives the below error
balancedTrain <- Balance(ls$train, "under")

# Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) :
# cannot coerce class '"function"' to a data.frame

# yet when ls$train is assigned to df, the object name used in Balance, it works
df <- ls$train
balancedTrain <- Balance(df, "under")
```

I'm not sure what's going on. Could anyone help?

Comment: ‘df’ is a function. So is ‘ls’ for that matter. You will get more informative error messages if you stop naming data objects with the names of functions.

Comment: Haha thanks, hadn't realised df was in use.